# Interface Callback working and showing toast while no message in the Textview

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-service

I have an interface callback , which check up on the service. It is working fine if I have to show any message in the Toast. But also I have to show those messages in the textview

When I start service , and start getting the callback while staying on the activity , I started to receive messages both in the form of toast and in the textview.

But When I go out of activity and came back again then I gets messages only in the form of toast but not in the Textview. What is the problem ?

Note:

Keep in mind  the normal xml state of that textview is gone but in the callback method I set it to visible then I set message in it.

For your reference here is that part in the call back

```
case DownloadService.STATUS_UPDATES:
            if (!resultData.isEmpty()) {

                if (resultData.getInt("updates", -1) != (-1) && resultData.getInt("total", -1) != (-1)) {
                    int updates = resultData.getInt("updates");
                    int total = resultData.getInt("total");

                    tv_newUpdates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_new_updates);

                        tv_newUpdates.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv_newUpdates.setText("Downloading " + updates + " of " + total + " pics.. ");
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Downloading " + updates + " is completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


               // this method is getting call back and showing message in text view tv_newUpdates
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how your callback has connection with your service

Comment: why ? it is not important

Comment: I think your textView is reinitalized to some other view.. I cannot give correct sollution without understanding your code...

Comment: Ofcourse My textView is re initialized when I pressed back and come back again into my activity.

Comment: now what would you recommend @PrasannaAnbu

Comment: Atleast tell me what it is. Is it a callback or resultReciever, How you are passing your callbak object to your service...

Comment: yes its result reciever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100154/discussion-between-allay-khalil-and-prasanna-anbu).

Comment: what do you mean by passing your callback object